# Python how to assign value to multiple rows in one column dataframe, without additional column being added

Tags: python, pandas

I have made a  dataframe consisting of 540 rows and one column using

```py
my_schedule = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(540), columns=np.arange(1))
```

throughout the code, I want to assign certain strings to blocks of rows.
I do this partly by using the following code and variations of this code.

```py
work_options = {120: [120, 60, 30], 60: [60, 30], 30: [30], 29: [3]}
office_activity = f' office_{s}'

while tick < 540:
    
    if my_schedule.iloc[(tick + 1):(tick + 121), 0].isnull().all():
        next_space = random.choices(['office', 'coffee', 'restroom'], transitionmatrix.iloc[row, :])
        
        if next_space == ['office']:
            office_time = random.choice([30, 60, 120])
            
            if office_time == 30:
                my_schedule.iloc[tick:(tick + 60), 0] = office_activity
                tick += 30
                
            elif office_time == 60:
                my_schedule.iloc[tick:(tick + 60), 0] = office_activity
                tick += 60
                
            elif office_time == 120:
                my_schedule.iloc[tick:(tick + 120), 0] = office_activity
                tick += 120
```

The tick is a value between 0 and 540 and thus responds to the rows in the dataframe. The problem is that even though I initialized a dataframe with only one column and want to assign the values for this one column and multiple rows, the outcome is that it expands the dataframe to have multiple columns and also copies the "office_activity" string there, as can be seen in the picture.

[The outcome I get now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyEnd.png)

What I want is it to only be assigned to the existing column '0' and no column being automatically added.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figure out what's causing the multiple columns in the code, but the code below might work for you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

my_schedule = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(540), columns=np.arange(1))

nrow,ncol = my_schedule.shape

work_options = {120: [120, 60, 30], 60: [60, 30], 30: [30], 29: [3]}

tick = 0
while tick < nrow:
    next_space = random.choices(['office', 'coffee', 'restroom'],weights=(1,4,10))[0]
    if next_space == 'office':
        office_time = random.choice([30, 60, 120])
        my_schedule.iloc[tick:(tick + office_time), 0] = f'office_{office_time}'
        tick += office_time
    else:
        my_schedule.iloc[tick, 0] = next_space
        tick += 1

pd.value_counts(my_schedule[0])
```